# HDMI output missing from JACK

Tags: sound, hdmi, jack

I'm trying to take advantage of the HDMI audio output on my video card within JACK, but the HDMI output device doesn't appear within JACK. I've created a zip file full of documentation, which you can retrieve from my GDrive here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g0LhZo3A3bEE8_Ef2M9lzV-pJkGkU60-/view?usp=sharing

1. Output from `dmesg`
2. Output from `aplay -l`
3. Output from `aplay -L`
4. Output from `inxi -Fxxxrz`
5. Screenshot of PulseAudio Volume Control, showing that the HDMI output device exists and works
6. Screenshot of Cadence before JACK is started
7. Screenshot of JACK configuration
8. Screenshot of Catia after starting JACK, showing that the HDMI output device is missing
9. Screenshot of several windows illustrating that the PulseAudio to JACK bridge works

I hope it's something simple that I just haven't learned yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, one more thing...the "system" device you see is the motherboard's integrated sound chip, not the one I want to use.

Comment: Hello. A couple of things. First others can not see the content of your google drive. And if it is a zip no one will take the time to dl and unzip it. Second comments is not where you add more info for your question. It is where others ask you. All additional info needs to be added to the question via edit. BTW I do not see a version of Ubuntu in the question.

Comment: That link to the file on my GDrive is a public link, anyone can get to it. The specific OS is Mint 20.3, which is based on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Sorry Mint is not Ubuntu and not supported on this site.